# Is it possible to use zonal histogram or equivelent with virtual layers

Tags: qgis, virtual-layer

I am trying to extract the areas of several land cover classes within a buffer polygon, and want them to change when the underlying polygons are edited.

My current work flow is:

1. edit polygon
2. buffer calculated with virtual layers
3. use `zonal histogram` to extract values from raster layer with several zones
4. ... more steps downstream....

Is there an algorithm to use for raster extraction/ zonal histograms in QGIS virtual layers?
The number of classes is fairly low and set, so it would be reasonable to hard code the classes and calculate the number of cells with raster value == 1 in one field, the number of cells with raster value == 2, etc.

Alternatively, the raster could be polygonized, either as one layer or one for each class, if there is a virtual layer algorithm that can calculate the area of polygons within the buffer polygon. The cover classes started out